# Query new Object List

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I need some query to get new objects. My result object is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MegrendelesNap {

    int year;
    int ora;

    public MegrendelesNap(int year, int ora) {
        this.year = year;
        this.ora = ora;
    }
}
```

So I need to get two integers in the constructor. In the interface I created one query:

```
 @Query("select new hu.langos.domain.MegrendelesNap(" +
            "FUNCTION('YEAR',d.datum), sum(d.ora) " +
            ") from Dolgozoora  d where d.megrendeles.id =:myid group by function('YEAR',d.datum)")
    List<MegrendelesNap>getMegredelesNapok(Long myid);
```

However, when I run my program I get this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable
>   to locate appropriate constructor on class
>   [hu.langos.domain.MegrendelesNap]. Expected arguments are: int, long

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SUM of Integers is not Integer! The sum of Integers return LONG!!